# Searching email in imap Node.js Gmail

Tags: node.js, imap

I am using imap package in my project I have read the documentation and I found this for searching in email with google search extensions:

> search() criteria extensions:
>
> X-GM-RAW - string - Gmail's custom search syntax. Example:
> 'has:attachment in:unread' X-GM-THRID - string - Conversation/thread
> id X-GM-MSGID - string - Account-wide unique id X-GM-LABELS - string -
> Gmail label

I want to search email with the criteria 'has:attachment'.

How can i use this ?

My imap.search fields like this:

```html
const Imap = require('imap');
const base64 = require('base64-stream')
var buffer = require("buffer");
var fs = require("fs");
const { simpleParser } = require('mailparser');
const imapConfig = {
  user: 'no-replay@mymail.com.br',
  password: 'mypass',
  host: 'imap.gmail.com',
  port: 993,
  tls: true,
};



const getEmails = () => {
  try {
    const imap = new Imap(imapConfig);
    imap.once('ready', () => {
      imap.openBox('INBOX', false, () => {
        imap.search(['ALL', ['FROM', 'rodrigo.barros.dsn@gmail.com']], (err, results) => {
          const f = imap.fetch(results, { bodies: '' });
          f.on('message', msg => {
            msg.on('body', stream => {
              simpleParser(stream, async (err, parsed) => {
                // const {from, subject, textAsHtml, text} = parsed;
                console.log('Imprimindo Parsed:')
                console.log(parsed);
                /* Make API call to save the data
                   Save the retrieved data into a database.
                   E.t.c
                */
              });
            });
            msg.once('attributes', attrs => {
              const { uid } = attrs;
              imap.addFlags(uid, ['\\Seen'], () => {
                // Mark the email as read after reading it
                console.log('Marked as read!');
              });
            });
          });
          f.once('error', ex => {
            return Promise.reject(ex);
          });
          f.once('end', () => {
            console.log('Done fetching all messages!');
            imap.end();
          });
        });
      });
    });

    imap.once('error', err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    imap.once('end', () => {
      console.log('Connection ended');
    });

    imap.connect();
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log('an error occurred');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in into an array. Like this:

```
imap.search(
[
    ['X-GM-RAW', 'has:attachment'],
    ['FROM', 'rodrigo.barros.dsn@gmail.com'],
],
(err, results) => {
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced this problem and after long trials i found this solution i like this :)

```js
imap.search(
[
    ['X-GM-RAW', 'has:unread'],
    ['FROM', 'mygmail@gmail.com'],
],
(err, results) => {
    // do something
});
```